# I need to know why a hyphen was used in this sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, punctuation

I just found this sentence from the book I am reading now.

"The revelation reminded of Stacey J., a would-be assassin I know well."

I think I got a nuance, but I need some logical explanation of the usage of hyphen in this sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It connects the two words and makes them into an adjective.

> **would-be**
>
> /ˈwʊdbi/
>
> adjective
>
> 1. desiring or aspiring to be a specified type of person. "a would-be
>      actress who dresses up as Marilyn Monroe"
>
> synonyms: aspiring, budding, promising, prospective, potential,
>   striving, hopeful, optimistic, keen, eager, ambitious, enterprising,
>   wishful, longing; informalwannabe  "would-be actors"
>
> noun informal
>
> noun: would-be; plural noun: would-bes
>
> 1. a person who desires or aspires to be a particular type. "a seemingly
>      endless queue of journalists and would-bes formed"

Answer (score 0):

The term 'would-be' implies 'wants to be, but isn't'; the hyphen connects the two words into a phrase which is somewhat different than a compound (combined) word. Its common to see hyphenated adjectives where nouns are more commonly compounded.